# How to correctly create Android emulator from command line with avdmanager?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

For some reason all emulators, which I created using avdmanager, don't work.

To be sure that I'm doing it correctly I opened https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager.html and copied example:

> ./avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"
>
> ./emulator -avd test

Emulator starts (as before) but unfortunately shows black screen:
[image: Android emulator]

How to correctly create Android emulator from command line with avdmanager?

Answer (score 3):

Try following steps:

```
touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg

cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin

./sdkmanager --verbose --list
```

Here I am creating android api 25.

```
./sdkmanager --verbose "system-images;android-25;google_apis_playstore;x86"
```

To list all the devices

```
./avdmanager list device
```

To list all targets(versions of android operating system)

```
./avdmanager list targets
```

AVDs are combinations of targets and devices

```
./avdmanager create avd -n nexus6p -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis_playstore;x86" -b x86 -c 2048M -f
```

Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? [no]

just press enter

Comment: but how to choose existing hardware profile? how to make sure created avd isn't with 320x480 resolution?

Comment: @Ewoks Use the 'avdmanager list' to look at the hardware profiles then use the '-d <id>' on the end of the avdmanager create line to use that exact hardware profile.